# How to update the x and y axis while reading and plotting the live data from a file?

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.7

I am reading a serial port and logging data to the files for every certain time period. After all processing, i am having the time stamp(ex.14:2:2) and the value(ex. 12.3) in my hand. i need to plot the time stamp , the value in a graph and update it simultaneously as the data according to what is being written into the files via another script.

it is working but as the samples grow, the plot becomes clumsy(ticks difference is getting low). How can i do the update of x axis and y axis limit as the data arrives?

I am new to matplotlib and have tried this code in windows with python 3.6 and its working for small x axis and y axis data.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.tight_layout()

def plotDataOf(i,file):
   totalLines = open(file,"r").read()
   lines = totalLines.split('\n')
   xlist = []
   ylist = []
   for line in lines:
        if len(line)>1:
           x,y = line.split(',')
           xlist.append(x)
           ylist.append(y)
   ax1.clear()
   ax1.grid()
   ax1.plot(xlist,ylist)
   plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
   plt.title(file.split('.')[0])
   plt.ylabel('Data')

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plotDataOf,fargs=[userFile], interval=1000)
 plt.show()
```

I expect the x axis and y axis grow in according to the data in the file without get ugly on the plot.

Comment: You forgot to convert your strings to numbers

Comment: actually, my data is in strings. as i append them in lists they grow larger and larger , finally the plot shrinks

Comment: So suppose you have `"A", "B", "C"`, then from a certain point on you want to omit `"B"` and just show `"A"` and `"C"`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for the reply. my requirement is to extend the x axis and y axis as the lists grows. the plot is very nice for fewer samples but fails as data increases.Can you suggest any idea?

Comment: You want a larger figure? (In the sense of, at the start the figure is 50 pixels, and as more data comes in it grows to 1000 pixels or so.)

Comment: not exactly but please suggest how to do it. i want any figure size while lets say x-axis grows on plotting data without disturbing previous sample.as the data is coming on, it should go on drawing until the data is not available.

Comment: Does the `ax.set_xlim` method get you what you need?

Comment: can you tell me how to use set xlim in matplotlib on time in which is in string format.ex("14:4:4") ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you are really great. I am really new to this. After lots of searching, I am back again to your first comment. I converted those timestamp strings to int to draw on the plot. but they are getting rounded like after 140459, i am getting 140460 which is not correct as per time. Can you suggest how to stick to the time format and stop time getting rounded off in the plot?